# Boto3: Issue Copying metadata for large files from one bucket to other bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Metadata is not copied when file size is 10 MB or greater.
When Copying object from one s3 bucket to other s3 bucket, file copy is successful but metadata is missing when file size is greater than 10 MB.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
source_bucket = {'Bucket':'s3bucket1','Key':'app/a.xml'}
s3.meta.client.copy(source_bucket,'targets3bucket','app/a.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `copy_from` to ensure that metadata is preserved.  Here's a function to do that when copying an object from one bucket (old bucket) to another (new bucket):

```py
def copy_object_from_old_to_new_bucket(
    s3_key: str,
    old_bucket: service_resource.Bucket,
    new_bucket: service_resource.Bucket,
) -> None:
    """
    Move an object from the old to the new bucket.
    """
    # Select the new location of the object (s3_key doesn't have to exist).
    target_object = new_bucket.Object(s3_key)

    # Copy the message.
    target_object.copy_from(
        CopySource=f"{old_bucket.name}/{s3_key}",
        MetadataDirective="COPY",
    )
```

For reference:

- [here's a github bug](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3378) which mentions this too.
- [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/copy-object.html) on copying objects
- [copy_from docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy_from)